# Report exceeds 256 columns

Tags: c#, sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I've recently discovered that I cannot export a SSRS report to Excel if it contains more than 256 Columns. Is there a work around for this as this is in place for backwards compatibility with Excel 2003 and older versions. I intend to use Excel 2007+ for the reports.

**Error Thrown in the Report Designer**

[image: Error Thrown in the Report Designer]

**Edit**

I've exported a smaller report to Excel and found that it is merging 2 cells for every column, so in this case the should only be around 210 columns. How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: We had this issue a long back and we realized that `office` component that was installed on Report Server was office 2003. If it could be 2007+ then report would have performed better.. So check `Office` version on your `Report Server`.

Comment: Its the file type more than the version, even with 2007 if it is still a .xls the limit still applys

Comment: It has to be a .xlsx file. Than your limits are 1,048,576 rows by 16,384 columns. Take from the [excel limit spec](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3).

Comment: @Matt If `Report Server` is not equipped with right version of `office` tool then he will never get desired behavior of Excel.

Comment: @AmneshGoel  how do I check the office component version?

Comment: Go to the `Program & Features` under `Control Panel` on your `Report Server`. You will find `Office` component there. Get it upgrade to 2007.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, Excel 2003 supports a maximum of 256 columns.
SSRS 2008 generates Excel 2003 documents so you will fall into the same limitations.

Here is what you can do:

- Upgrade to SSRS 2012 which generates Excel 2007-2010 and supports 16,384 columns
- Export to CSV instead
- Re-organize your content to have less columns, [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/32f28407-e1ca-457e-92fd-d292e32dde4e/limit-no-of-columns-in-ssrs-matrix-report?forum=sqlreportingservices) is a workaround for example